# no irq handler vector

Tags: linux, centos

I've just installed CentOS 6.4 on my desktop machine. Everytime I start my terminal I get these error messages and I can't figure out why. How can I trace the problem and fix it?

```
Message from syslogd@dan-p4 at Jan 16 18:52:50 ...
 kernel:do_IRQ: 0.115 No irq handler for vector (irq -1)
```

Comment: Which motherboard? `dmidecode -t 2`

Comment: @Sukminder do you mean: `sudo dmidecode -t 2`? As w/o sudo, you will get the version of `dmidecode`, but with sudo, you will get a lot more info.

Comment: @Kevdog777: Yes, as privileged user / root.

Comment: [root@dan-p4 dan]# dmidecode -t 2
# dmidecode 2.11
SMBIOS 2.4 present.

Handle 0x0002, DMI type 2, 15 bytes
Base Board Information
 Manufacturer: ASRock
 Product Name: 4CoreDual-SATA2.
 Version:                       
 Serial Number:                       
 Asset Tag:                       
 Features:
  Board is a hosting board
  Board is replaceable
 Location In Chassis:                       
 Chassis Handle: 0x0003
 Type: Motherboard
 Contained Object Handles: 0

Comment: Do you have a NVidia graphic card and did you use their kernel drivers?

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't solve why you're getting these messages but to just suppress these messages you can use this command:

```
$ dmesg -n 1
```

Add this to your user's `~/.bashrc` to make this change permanent. Ultimately it sounds like you have a feature enabled in your BIOS that is not either supported or not configured correctly. You can also try disabling unused features in your BIOS to try eliminating these messages permanently.